# laracasts tutorial authentication fails

Tags: php, authentication, laravel-4, passwords

I tried running the code below and I found out "storage of user password is not working properly". I tried deleting all the entries on the database but the problem still persist. This is the code:

```
 $user = new User;
 $user->fname = 'joe';
 $user->lname = 'joe';
 $user->email = 'joe@gmail.com';
 $user->password = Hash::make('123456');
 if ( ! ($user->save()))
 {
     dd('user is not being saved to database properly - this is the problem');          
 }

 if ( ! (Hash::check('123456', Hash::make('123456'))))
 {
     dd('hashing of password is not working correctly - this is the problem');          
 }

 if ( ! (Auth::attempt(array('email' => 'joe@gmail.com', 'password' => '123456'))))
 {
     dd('storage of user password is not working correctly - this is the problem');          
 }

 else
 {
     dd('everything is working when the correct data is supplied - so the problem is related to your forms and the data being passed to the function');
 }
```

What could be the cause of this problem? I am trying to make an authentication for login.

Answer (score 0):

oh this is just a silly error, i did tried changing my length/values of password and username field on database from 50 to 255. then deleting all the records of the database. after doing so my login authentication is now working.